# how to pass a variable into another function

Tags: jquery

i am trying to get the variable from one jquery block of code into another to perform a certain task.
i have a form that the user fills in, they have two option but one is set by default. option one, option two is shown by clicking a button which then replaces option one.

jquery

```
$("#opt2").click(function(){
var newopt = $("name").val();
$("#opt1").replaceWith('<input type="text" id="name">');
});

$("#ipload").click(function(){
alert(newopt);
});
```

but this comes up undefined event when i enter some data, i know some may say its not apart of the previous function. so my question is how can i get newopt to alert into the second function, when i click ipload

Answer (score 2):

Because you declared the variable newopt in a function it is only accessible within that function.

So to make newopt available elsewhere, declare it outside any function like so:

```
var newopt;
$("#opt2").click(function(){
newopt = $("name").val();
$("#opt1").replaceWith('<input type="text" id="name">');
});

$("#ipload").click(function(){
alert(newopt);
});
```

But this code *still* won't work - you've missed the # out of the selector to indicate you want the value of the div with id name - this will work:

```
var newopt;
$("#opt2").click(function(){
newopt = $("#name").val();
$("#opt1").replaceWith('<input type="text" id="name">');
});

$("#ipload").click(function(){
alert(newopt);
});
```

You can learn more about scope in javascript here - http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/01/what-you-need-to-know-about-javascript-scope/

Answer (score 1):

You had made newopt a local variable of the first function. Therefore it would not be seen by the second. Try this:

```
var newopt="";

$("#opt2").click(function()
{
    newopt = $("name").val();
    $("#opt1").replaceWith('<input type="text" id="name">');
});

$("#ipload").click(function()
{
    alert(newopt);
});
```

Comment: As mentioned in other posts there's something wrong with the `newopt = $("name").val();` line. You probably mean `newopt = $("#name").val();`

Answer (score 0):

You can make the variable global also is `$("name").val();` suppose to be `$("#name").val();`, if so then why are you adding another element with the same id, id should be unique.